# Error: Could not find path GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

im just learning WPF and im following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqJUg-HXV3c
I don't know why but for some reason my code is returning this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\realj\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\wpf_lessons_observablecollection_listview\wpf_lessons_observablecollection_listview\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\wpf_lessons_observablecollection_listview_npm4zagv_wpftmp.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'.  wpf_lessons_observablecollection_listview   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets   191
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace wpf_lessons_observablecollection_listview
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            entries = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> entries;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Entries
        {
            get { return entries; }
            set { entries = value; }
        }

        private string textBox;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public string TextBox
        {
            get { return textBox; }
            set 
            { 
                textBox = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Entries.Add(TextBox);
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

i tried to chatgpt this and chatgpt doesnt really know what to do. on google, i can't find anything that is specific to my situation

Comment: Looks like your path is too long.